# how to Load data from last modified files within one day from subfolders Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following directory structure on an Azure container:

```
-dwh-prod
  -Main_Folder
   -2021-01
     -file1.parquet
   -2021-02
     -file2.parquet
     -file3.parquet
```

where the Data is partitioned by year and month to create subfolders. Within these sub-folders, I have my data files. I want to load into my data flow only the latest files that were added within one day from running my data flow pipeline.

I tried using currentUTC() in End Time and subtracting one day -> AddDays(currentUTC(), -1) in Start Time in the 'Filter by last modified' option provided in source options but it didn't work.

I also tried using currentTimestamp() instead but to no avail.

[image]

[image]

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? It seems since the folders are named based on date, then you should be able to target the folder without worrying about the last modified filter. Also, how is your Source Data Set configured?

Comment: The subfolders are populated by a pipeline that is triggered daily, and the data is partitioned based on year and month. So It is true that I want to target the last folder that I have, but within that folder, I want to load only the files created from the last pipeline run, especially that these subfolders are created dynamically as we go from month to month and year to year. I updated the question with the source data set configuration. @JoelCochran

Comment: @amro_ghoneim I tried this and it can work for me. When you do the things as your screenshot shows, it would give you all parquet file in your Main_Folder?

Comment: @SteveZhao yes that's generally what happens. but I was even trying to set the values manually and it didn't find any files: 'Path does not resolve to any file(s). Please make sure the file/folder exists and is not hidden.'

Comment: @amro_ghoneim So your expression is right. It seems there is something wrong with your path of the dataset. Please make sure your path is correct. I notice that your folder path is MainFolder in your dataset, however you say your files are stored in Main_Folder. Could it be this that caused your error?

Comment: @SteveZhao This is a mistake on my end in the question only. This solution works when The MainFolder has the files directly, without any extra sub-directories. How can I extend it to the sub-directory structure?

Comment: @amro_ghoneim You can try to set Wildcard paths setting in your Source options(In your first screenshot). Try to type this in it: `Main_Folder/*/*.parquet`.

Comment: @SteveZhao This works yes! well that was simple. Thank you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is correct. Please change the folder path from MainFolder to Main_folder in your dataset and set `Main_Folder/*/*.parquet` as your Wildcard paths  in your Source option. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is close, but I'm not sure the folder name is sufficient. I'm also not familiar with "currentUTC". The correct function should be [utcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#utcNow).

Below is an outline of how I would approach this problem.

**Source Dataset**

Add a Parameter for the subfolder (year-month):

[image]

and then set the Folder path to an expression like:

[image]

**Pipeline**

You could either pass in the subfolder or calculate it at runtime. My preference would be to pass it in as a parameter:

[image]

I would then add variables to calculate the start and end times. Since you are running this daily, I would be sure to force the time to the START of the day(s). This should handle any vagaries based on run time. Also, I would use the built in [getPastTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#getPastTime) function:

[image]
[image]

Now use these objects in your Source configuration:

[image]

Comment: As OP's screenshot shows, he's using data flow. So use `currentUTC()` is correct.

Comment: Thanks @SteveZhao - I totally missed that!